# jquery.gantt vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, gantt-chart

How can I add a vertical scroll bar to jquery.gantt like the one seen at http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/z6t5k7qv/

```
no code
```

Or alternatively make the date headers sticky at the top of the page (tried various sticky plugins without success).

Any ideas or code much appreciated.